# Incrementing ISO date by 5 days

Tags: python, datetime

I am working with a date format that looks like this:

```
2023-04-25T16:00:00+00:00
```

I want to add 5 days to the `current_date` and return the same format as above

I tried this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.now()
iso_date = today.isoformat()
iso_date += timedelta(days=5)
```

which throws:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str(not "datetime.timedelta") to str
```

Comment: You need to add the time delta to a data object, not a string. In your example that would be `today + timedelta(days=5)`. It you are starting from a string, covert it to a data object with something like: `datetime.fromisoformat()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of `isoformat()` is a string. Your `timedelta` should be added to the Date object, not the string:

```py
today = datetime.now()
today += timedelta(days=5)
iso_date = today.isoformat()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.now()
future_date = today + timedelta(days=5)
iso_date = future_date.isoformat()

print(iso_date)
```

Output:

```
2023-05-24T12:28:17.392856
```